# Pop Up in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know is there any possibility to design the popup as below in xamarin.forms.

[image]

Comment: there are plugins you can use for popup dialogs - however, if you specifically want it to look like the iOS popover dialog you probably need to use a custom renderer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are ***many*** ways to do this, here is one that avoids writing a custom render for each platform...

Using `NControl`/`Ngraphics` you can create an `NControlView` subclass that draws your popover (i.e. an iOS Popover). You can then embed it into XAML and do what ever you need in terms of positioning, add controls on top of it, blurring the background, etc...

[image]

```
public class PopDownControl : NControlView
{
    public PopDownControl()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent;
    }

    public static BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(int), typeof(PopDownControl), 0,
            BindingMode.OneWay, null, (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
            {
                (bindable as PopDownControl).Invalidate();
            });

    public int CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static BindableProperty InsetPositionProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InsetPosition), typeof(int), typeof(PopDownControl), 0,
            BindingMode.OneWay, null, (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
            {
                (bindable as PopDownControl).Invalidate();
            });

    public int InsetPosition
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(InsetPositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InsetPositionProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void Draw(ICanvas canvas, Rect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas, rect);

        var backgroundBrush = new SolidBrush(Colors.White);
        var pen = new Pen(Colors.White, 2);

        var width = rect.Width - CornerRadius;
        var height = rect.Height;
        var arcdia = CornerRadius * 2;
        var inset = InsetPosition;
        var insetWidth = 30;
        canvas.DrawPath(
          new PathOp[]
           {
                new MoveTo (arcdia + CornerRadius, CornerRadius),
                new LineTo (inset, CornerRadius),
                new LineTo (inset + (insetWidth / 2), 0),
                new LineTo (inset + insetWidth, CornerRadius),
                new LineTo (width-arcdia, CornerRadius),
                new ArcTo (new Size (arcdia), false, true, new Point (width, arcdia + CornerRadius)),
                new LineTo (width, height-arcdia),
                new ArcTo (new Size (arcdia), false, true, new Point (width-arcdia, height)),
                new LineTo (arcdia + CornerRadius, height),
                new ArcTo (new Size (arcdia), false, true, new Point (CornerRadius, height-arcdia)),
                new LineTo (arcdia / 2, arcdia + CornerRadius),
                new ArcTo (new Size (arcdia), false, true, new Point (arcdia + CornerRadius, CornerRadius)),
                new LineTo (arcdia + CornerRadius, CornerRadius),
                new ClosePath(),
           }, pen, backgroundBrush);
    }
}
```

- https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl
- https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics

Comment: @SushiHanover,I tried your approach,but iam not getting it like i wanted,can you please share some more details for this.

Answer (score 3):

**Rg.Plugins.Popup** is best plugin for your requirement. It is awesome plugin for Xamarin.Forms.
You can find more detail [here](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).

[image]

Comment: Best of all, the code is 100% shared, meaning an implementation without renderers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slideOverkit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit) component in Xamarin.Forms to implement slideover [popup](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit/master/website/img/portfolio/PopOverPage-iOS.gif) as per your design.