# Popup inside Xamarin Forms listview

Tags: xaml, listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, popup

I try to achieve this in my app but not get success How can I do it Please help me to achieve this.

[image]

My List View Code is below.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="HighlightList" ItemsSource="{Binding Highlights}" SeparatorVisibility="None" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" HasUnevenRows="True" IsVisible="{Binding IsViewVisible}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                    <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" Margin="10,5" BorderColor="#e0e4e2" IsClippedToBounds="True"  CornerRadius="10">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="{Binding NoteData.NoteColor, Converter={converters:HighlightColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" WidthRequest="10"/>


                            <Label Text="{Binding NoteData.NoteText}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"  Margin="5,10,0,5" MaxLines="15" LineHeight="1.5"/>
                            <Label Text="Page Number : 5 Added on 01-03-2020" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="10" Margin="5,0,0,10">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding PageNumber, StringFormat='Page Number : {0}'}" />
                                        <Span Text="{Binding DisplayCreatedDate, StringFormat=' Added on {0: dd-MM-yyyy}'}" />
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            <ImageButton Source="more" HeightRequest="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,10,15,0" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference HighlightList}, Path=BindingContext.SelectHeighlightCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Frame>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ListView already has a standard contextmenu concept - is there a reason you need to define your own UX for this?

Comment: Thanks @Jason for the reply. How can I achieve this? The client gives this requirement so  I need to do it. actually I want open RG popup on specific position But I am not getting the exact position of the button in screen

Comment: Hi ho through this https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/245

Comment: and check this alsohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912031/pop-up-in-xamarin-forms